# Blocked out of server because I don't have access to usual ssh public key, any solution?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, public-key

I momentarily don't have access to my usual computer and would like to work on my personal dev server (Raspberry Pi) as usual using ssh. My problem is I secured it so you can only log in it with my public ssh key and disabled the password login option.

Is there any way I can log on it by a different why? Can I add an ssh key by pulling out the Raspberry Pi SD card and plugging it in on an other computer?

I'm guessing I won't be allowed to do so and will have to wait to get my usual computer back… I'll learn from my errors and put my public key on an external drive for next time…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could theoretically pull the SD card, mount the filesystem on another machine, and then modify the install as required. Additionally, you could get a serial console via a PL2303-based adapter connected to the UART0 signals on the board and get a command line that way, assuming the distro you chose provides one and that you didn't disable it.